# Xgboost algorithm issue file empty

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, xgboost, xgbclassifier, xgbregressor

I trying to train a dataset using the Xgboost algorithm for 1.7-1 version . While calling Xgboost function it is throwing out error as follows .

```
2024-01-19:02:57:27:INFO] Imported framework sagemaker_xgboost_container.training
[2024-01-19:02:57:27:INFO] No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
[2024-01-19:02:57:27:INFO] Invoking user training script.
[2024-01-19:02:57:27:ERROR] Reporting training FAILURE
[2024-01-19:02:57:27:ERROR] framework error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/tarfile.py", line 2318, in next
    tarinfo = self.tarinfo.fromtarfile(self)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/tarfile.py", line 1105, in fromtarfile
    obj = cls.frombuf(buf, tarfile.encoding, tarfile.errors)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/tarfile.py", line 1041, in frombuf
    raise EmptyHeaderError("empty header")
tarfile.EmptyHeaderError: empty header
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_trainer.py", line 84, in train
    entrypoint()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/training.py", line 102, in main
    train(framework.training_env())
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/training.py", line 87, in train
    framework.modules.run_module(
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_modules.py", line 290, in run_module
    _files.download_and_extract(uri, _env.code_dir)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_files.py", line 131, in download_and_extract
    with tarfile.open(name=dst, mode="r:gz") as t:
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/tarfile.py", line 1621, in open
    return func(name, filemode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/tarfile.py", line 1674, in gzopen
    t = cls.taropen(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/tarfile.py", line 1651, in taropen
    return cls(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/tarfile.py", line 1514, in __init__
    self.firstmember = self.next()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/tarfile.py", line 2333, in next
    raise ReadError("empty file")
tarfile.ReadError: empty file
empty file
```

I have two source files having same structure with .csv extension .
I am not sure why it is complaining of tar file empty

Comment: please add your code so that other people know how it run and generate this error

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved the . Model output (.tar gz ) was not generated as there is a bug in the entry point python code . rectified entry point code and now working fine.